# how to let each element in a vector be plotted in 1 second on the x axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a vector x=[0 0 0 1 1 2 1 3 1 4] i need to plot it as stairs graph but the space between each element and the another one on the x axis must be  1 unit or 1 second for example , as when the vector elements increase the matlab plot more than one element in the same unit on x axis

so how can i adjust the x axis to plot each element in 1 second on x axis ?